# Trigger a pop-up or recenter in Openlayers (version 7.x-2.0-beta5) from outsite the map

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to trigger the pop-up of a marker or center the marker in an Openlayers map through an anchor-tag outside the Openlayers map.

Example:

- Create a view that lists some nodes
- Click on the title of a node
- Recenter the map or open the pop-up of the marker of that node.

I found this solution but they work with an older version of Openlayers and can't get it to work...

Comment: I actually think you need to refer to the OL docs for this. From my (limited) experience with OL, you need to interact with the OL API, and there's little or no Drupal related functionality involved. I could be wrong though, hence not voting off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard popups that come with [OL](https://drupal.org/project/Openlayers), you can make use of `Drupal.openlayers.popup.popupSelect.clickFeature()`.

The way I did this was to assign an html attribute "nid" to each node in the list of nodes that you are going to use for the click navigation.  You can grab the nid from the clicked node any way you like, this is just the way I had done it.

So, now you have your list of nodes with an nid attribute and your map full of markers.  Here's one way you can use `Drupal.openlayers.popup.popupSelect.clickFeature()` to open the popup when you click one of the nodes in your list:

Make sure namespace exists:

```
Drupal.settings.nid = Drupal.settings.nid || [];
Drupal.settings.getAllFeature;
```

Make Drupal aware of all layers features:

```
function my_map() {
  var all_layers = Drupal.openlayers.popup.popupSelect.layers;
  for(var key1 in all_layers) {
    var current_layer = all_layers[key1];
    var all_features_in_layer = current_layer.features;
    for(var key2 in all_features_in_layer) {
      var current_feature = all_features_in_layer[key2];
      Drupal.settings.nid[current_feature.attributes.nid] = current_feature;
    }
  }
}
```

Function to grab the map object:

```
function getMap() {
  return jQuery('.openlayers-map').data('openlayers');
}
```

Click function for each node in your list of nodes:

```
jQuery('.eachNodeInYourList').click(function(e) {
  var nid = jQuery(this).attr('nid');
  show_popup(nid);      
});
```

Show the popup on the map:

```
function show_popup(nid) {
  if (Drupal.settings.nid) {
    var feature = Drupal.settings.nid[nid];
    Drupal.openlayers.popup.popupSelect.clickFeature(feature);
  }
}
```

Make sure a layer is visible: (get the layer name from the "Title" field on the views overlay)

```
function activate_layer(aLayer) {
  var ol = getMap();
  var layer = ol.openlayers.getLayersByName(aLayer)[0];
  layer.setVisibility(true);
}
```

Initialize:

```
if (jQuery('.openlayers-map').length > 0) {
  my_map();
  activate_layer('myLayer');
}
```

Comment: I found information about _clickFeature_ but looking into the **openlayers_behaviour_popup.js** I can't find any _clickfeature_ so I tried to use _onSelect_, but without success. (line 60 of the js)